# Why a default assignment operator not synthesis by compiler if a class has a reference data member

Tags: c++

In C++, if a class has a reference data member the default assignment operator is not synthesized by compiler. Why?

Comment: What would that reference be initialized to?

Comment: You can't _reassign_ a reference. Simply assigning would modify the referenced object, which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **In C++, if a class has a reference data member the default assignment operator is not synthesized by compiler. Why?**

What an copy assignment should do is defined in:

**C++03 Standard 12.8/13:**

> Each subobject is assigned in the manner appropriate to its type:
>
> - if the subobject is of class type, the copy assignment operator for the class is used (as if by explicit qualification; that is, ignoring any possible virtual overriding functions in more derived classes);
> - if the subobject is an array, each element is assigned, in the manner appropriate to the element type;
> - if the subobject is of scalar type, the built-in assignment operator is used.

In short It implies that ***each of the member should assigned in an appropriate manner***
which raises the question,
***What should be the behavior for assignment of a reference member in class?***
Consider the following about references:

1. References are inherently non assignable, they keep referring the same referrant to which they were initialized<sup>[Ref 1]</sup>.
2. By virtue of `#1` assigning to an reference doesn't reassign the reference, it changes the value of the referrant which is non-intuitive behavior.

There is no default correct behavior to be enforced here but a rather situational one.So the C++ Standard mandates that designer of the class is in best position to determine this behavior and hence the decision that default assignment operator should not be synthesized by compiler if a class has a reference data member.

This decision is specified in:
**C++03 Standard 12.8/12:**

> An implicitly-declared copy assignment operator is implicitly defined when an object of its class type is assigned a value of its class type or a value of a class type derived from its class type. A program is ill formed if the class for which a copy assignment operator is implicitly defined has:
> .......
> — a nonstatic data member of reference type, or
> .......

---

<sup>[Ref 1]</sup>
**C++03 Standard 8.5.3/2:**

> **A reference cannot be changed to refer to another object after initialization**. Note that initialization of a reference is treated very differently from assignment to it. Argument passing (5.2.2) and function value return (6.6.3) are initializations.

Answer (score 4):

Saw the discussion on a member-only forum. Since the answer is not well-known to most programmers, would like to post the answer and share it here.

From C++ standard draft N3337 §12.8.23:

> A defaulted copy/move assignment operator for class X is defined as deleted if X has:
>
> - a variant member with a non-trivial corresponding assignment operator and X is a
>   union-like class, or
> - a non-static data member of const non-class type (or array thereof), or
> - a non-static data member of reference type, or
> - a non-static data member of class type M (or array thereof) that cannot be
>   copied/moved because overload resolution (13.3), as applied to M’s corresponding
>   assignment operator, results in an ambiguity or a function that is deleted or
>   inaccessible from the defaulted assignment operator, or
> - a direct or virtual base class B that cannot be copied/moved because overload
>   resolution (13.3), as applied to B’s corresponding assignment operator, results in
>   an ambiguity or a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted
>   assignment operator, or
> - for the move assignment operator, a non-static data member or direct base class
>   with a type that does not have a move assignment operator and is not trivially
>   copyable, or any direct or indirect virtual base class.

Comment: It's great that you posted a quote from the standard, but it's more important to understand the *reason*: that the assignment operator would have to assign the reference member of the LHS object a new value, but references can't be re-assigned (they are implicitly const).